# Magento restore custom top navigatoin bar to default top navigation

Tags: magento, navigation

i'm using a theme that has a function of `custom menu` you can check this menu functionality from one premium theme http://www.emthemes.com/demo/#magento-theme-sunglasses-store-em0022 
There is no top.phtml file in my theme it's calling all menus through widget incorporated in cms block. This custom menu widget is not compatible to 1.7 so it's not functioning well in my store.

So far i edited my header.phtml file, from

```
<div class="nav-content"><div class="nav-container">
<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
    <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
    <?php else:?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_mainmenu') ?></div></div>
```

to

```
<div class="nav-content"><div class="nav-container">
<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
    <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
    <?php else:?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif?>
<?php echo $_menu; ?></div></div>
```

But still it's not working. So i went to my theme's `cms.xml`

```
<reference name="header">
        <block type="cms/block" name="cms_mainmenu">                
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>mainmenu</block_id></action>
        </block>
```

I thought the problem is with this code.
Did antone know how to overwrite this to show mt stores categories in fronend ?
please give me your suggestions to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

echo $menu;

Surely that should be $this->menu? Or whatever is building the menu in the custom block, unless your building the menu in the template